# How to loop through all the files in a folder (if the names of the files are unknown)?

Tags: java, loops

There is a folder: `C:\\Users\..myfolder`

It contains `.pdf` files (or any other, say .csv). I cannot change the names of those files, and I do not know the number of those files. I need to loop all of the files one by one.
How can I do this?

(I know how to do this if I knew the names)

Comment: Look at the methods of the `File` class, all you need is either in, or referenced from, there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `File.listFiles`

```
final File file = new File("whatever");
for(final File child : file.listFiles()) {
    //do stuff
}
```

You can use the `FileNameExtensionFilter` to filter your files too

```
final FileNameExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("N/A", "pdf", "csv"//, whatever other extensions you want);
final File file = new File("whatever");
for (final File child : file.listFiles()) {
    if(extensionFilter.accept(child)) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Annoyingly `FileNameExtensionFilter` comes from the `javax.swing` package so cannot be used directly in the `listFiles()` api, it is still more convenient than implementing a file extension filter yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much. Especially for the additional filter thingy ...

Comment: Consider using a FileFilter instead, then using File.listFiles(FileFilter).  For example, your FileFilter can check that each element is, indeed, a file and check the extension.

Comment: @rob Read the last part of the answer, there is no ready implementation of an extension filter in that api so there is little point in writing one yourself.

Comment: @BoristheSpider To clarify: `java.io.FileFilter` or `java.io.FilenameFilter`.  `FileNameExtensionFilter` is technically intended to be used with `JFileChooser`.

Comment: @rob you will notice from [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.java) that there are no dependencies on other swing classes. It is fine to use outside of swing.

Comment: Maybe should be `if(extensionFilter.accept(child)) {` instead of `if(extensionFilter.accept(file)) {`?

Comment: @Buras fair point - typo. Fixed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Although there aren't dependencies on other Swing classes, I'm just pointing out that there are two other listFiles method signatures which are more correct for solving this problem.  For instance, FileNameExtensionFilter will return true for any directory because that's the correct behavior for a file chooser.  However, it is probably not the correct behavior in most other cases.

Comment: How can i create a String using path_to_dir + file name? i have tried to use StringBuffer("path").append("child") but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

`File.listFiles()` gives you an array of files in a folder. You can then split the filenames to get the extension and check if it is  `.pdf`.

```
File[] files = new File("C:\\Users\..myfolder").listFiles();
for (File file : files) {
    if (!file.isFile()) continue;

    String[] bits = file.getName().split(".");
    if (bits.length > 0 && bits[bits.length - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
        // Do stuff with the file
    }
}
```

Comment: Use File.listFiles(FilenameFilter) or File.listFiles(FileFilter) to only process results which have certain properties, such as filename extension.

Comment: String[] bits = file.getName().split("\\.");

Answer (score 3):

So you can have more options, try the **Java 7 NIO** way of doing this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> files = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/"))) {
        for (Path path : files) {
            System.out.println(path.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

You can also provide a filter for the paths in the form of a `DirectoryStream.Filter` implementation

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> files = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/"),
        new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
                return true; // or whatever you want
            }
        })
    ) {

        for (Path path : files) {
            System.out.println(path.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you can extract the anonymous class to an actual class declaration.

Note that this solution cannot return `null` like the `listFiles()` solution.

For a recursive solution, check out the `FileVisitor` interface. For path matching, use the `PathMatcher` interface along with `FileSystems` and `FileSystem`. There are examples floating around Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Java.io.File.listFiles()` method to get a list of all files and folders inside a folder.